# What is the $dF(X)$ in some integrals concerning probability densities?

Tags: definition, integral

On multiple occasions I've come across statements about integrals of

Considers the problem of minimizing the risk functional (Vapnik's Statistical Learning Theory)

$$ R(\alpha ) = \int Q(z, \alpha ) dF(z) $$

Is this the same as having the probability density $F_Z(z)$ multiplied by a differential of the random variable $dz$ like this?

$$ R(\alpha ) = \int Q(z, \alpha ) f_Z(z) dz $$

I've read somewhere that $dF(z)$ is the probability measure so why is this *different* from the second formulation. How should I think about $dF(z)$?

I've seen works

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=stieltjes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This notation refers to the [Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration) and $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of the random variable under consideration.  This integral form is a useful way to write expectations of functions of random variables in cases where you want to include both continuous and discrete cases (and mixed cases).  In the event that $Z$ is a continuous random variable with density function $f_Z$ we obtain:

$$R(\alpha) = \int Q(z, \alpha) dF(z) = \int Q(z, \alpha) f_Z(z) dz.$$

In the event that $Z$ is a discrete random variable with mass function $f_Z$ we obtain:

$$R(\alpha) = \int Q(z, \alpha) dF(z) = \sum_z Q(z, \alpha) f_z(z).$$

If $dF$ is to be considered an object of its own (as opposed to just being a component of the notation of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral) then its meaning must be established by context and usage.  It usually refers to an [infinitesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(infinitesimal)) induced by the cumulative distribution function $F$, which is technically a linear map.  With a slight abuse of notation it might refer to a measure, depending on context and usage.  What is certainly true is that the cumulative distribution function $F$ induces a unique probability measure for $X$ (this follows from the famous [Carathéodory extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem)) and we can write the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral as a Lebesgue integral with respect to that measure.  It is usual to denote this measure with some standard measure notation such as $\mu_Z$, $\mathbb{P}_Z$, etc.  I suppose it is possible that some texts might use the notation $dF$ for this measure, but that would not be standard notation, and it would be confusing.

Comment: What is $\alpha$, a parameter of the distribution $F$?

Comment: The parameter $\alpha$ is mentioned in the original question as one of the arguments of the function $Q$.  Presumably it is a control variable that affects the risk in the decision problem.  It is not a parameter of the distribution $F$.

Comment: So I could just as easily drop the $\alpha$ and write $\mathbb{E}[Q(Z)] = \int Q(z)dF_Z(z)$?

Comment: Well, that would change the nature of the function $Q$.  But yes, if $Q$ is not a function of $\alpha$ then you can write that.